# Accessing a git repository using https, despite it providing ssh access only

Tags: git, gitlab

We have an ssh repository which is only accessible using ssh.
I would like to import that one into Gitlab for easier viewing.

Unfortunately gitlab only allows access for https. Therefore I would like to set up a small proxy, providing an https interface backed up by the ssh connection.

Is there already some existing tool for that? Any good ideas otherwise?

---

Regarding the close votes, I am pretty sure there is no such tool. Therefore the question is how to build a proxy. (Questions about git tooling and configuration are quite common around here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the repository using ssh, then push a copy of it to Gitlab (using either ssh or https).

```
# Make a clone over ssh of your existing project
git clone git@somehost.com:myuser/myproject.git

# Add another remote that points to gitlab, and push to it
git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:myuser/myproject.git
git push -u gitlab master
```

Once a project has been imported to Gitlab, you can (if you want) go into the project's settings and set up mirroring using ssh. (Mirroring with ssh is ok; it is only for the initial import that Gitlab demands http/https.) This setting is in the Repository section in the project's settings, e.g. at

```
https://gitlab.com/{your_username}/{project_name}/settings/repository
```

Comment: Interesting. On settings/repository I only see "protected branches", "protected tags" and "deploy keys". - Could it be this feature is only available in the enterprise version?

Comment: @michas I was looking on gitlab.com (their public server). If you are using self-hosted Gitlab CE, it appears that release does not support repository mirroring. You can still do this though, just pull from your ssh remote and push to the gitlab remote, same way you did the initial import.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Even with the import it will not keep the repositories in sync without the mirroring feature of ee. - Seems like a separate (fetch/push) sync process is the only solution. thx.